# Cannot resolve symbol with AutoValue and IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, auto-value, gradle-apt-plugin

I have been trying to find the correct settings for IntelliJ's annotation processing in order for it to co-exist with Gradle's build process.

Whenever I build from IntelliJ I cannot get it to recognise the generated sources from the [gradle-apt-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin).

My requirements for my project are:

- Building between IntelliJ and Gradle should be seamless and not interfere with the process of each other
- I need to use IntelliJ's *Create separate module per source set* option
- I need to use IntelliJ's folder based structure
- IntelliJ needs to be able to recognise and autocomplete AutoValue classes

Here are the steps for a MCVE in order to reproduce the issue with IntelliJ 2017.2.4 and Gradle 3.5:

- Create a new Gradle project from IntelliJ
- Check the *Create separate module per source set* option
- Open *build.gradle* file:
- Add the following `plugins` block:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.12'
}
```

- Add the following `dependencies` block

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5'
    apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5'
}
```

- Go to *Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Annotation Processors*
- Check the *Enable Annotation Processing*
- Create a class:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class GeneratedSourcesTest {

    static GeneratedSourcesTest create(String field) {
        return new AutoValue_GeneratedSourcesTest(field);
    }

    public abstract String field();
}
```

- On IntelliJ run *Build → Build Project*
- Open the `GeneratedSourcesTest` class, on the static factory method, everything compiles fine but I get the error:

`cannot resolve symbol ‘AutoValue_GeneratedSourcesTest’`

How can I make the `AutoValue_GeneratedSourcesTest` class accessible from IntelliJ?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124090

Answer (score 15):

After importing your Gradle project under IDEA do the following steps:

1. Set annotation processing configuration as follows:
   [image]
2. Run menu: *Build - Build Project*
3. Right click on each new *generated* folder and select: *Mark Directory as - Generated Sources Root* so it was marked as follows:
   [image]

   4. Add `/generated` to project's *.gitignore* file

That's a minimal viable configuration which will provide full IDE support for generated classes.
The drawback is, whenever Gradle project gets re-imported the *generated* folders will need be marked as *Generated Sources Root* again.
Perhaps this can be improved with adding these paths as source sets under *build.gradle*.

Sometimes it happens that IDEA modules lose their *compiler output path* settings in result of the above. It's sufficient to just set it back to their default folders.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Performing first 2 steps worked for me. But why is that things like these always make you struggle, no matter which IDE you are working with?

Comment: Wow! thanks for the detailed answer! also worth to mention to use [AutoValue Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8091-autovalue-plugin) that make life even easier :)

Answer (score 3):

The answers are (should be) in the README for the gradle-apt-plugin: https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin

Namely, also apply the `net.ltgt.apt-idea` plugin.

Btw, I recommend delegating build/run actions to Gradle in IntelliJ. Sure it's a bit slower, but requires zero setup in the IDE and works reliably. That said, it should also work OK if you don't.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think that the idea plugin obliges me to use file based settings. I would much rather use folder based settings for code format reasons.

Comment: Assuming you mean `.idea/` vs. `*.iws`, then no, absolutely not. I used folder based settings in Idea, with the Gradle integration (**not** the `idea` task), along with delegating build/run actions to Gradle.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and correction. That sounds great. I will go back and investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Just have your build.gradle with these and it works fine, no need of touching intellij, source set etc..

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.20"

}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt-idea'
group 'abc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile             "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.2"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have to do anything to intellij using maven by adding the optional true tag.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: we're talking about gradle

Comment: The title says "Cannot resolve symbol with AutoValue and IntelliJ" and this is a way to fix it if you are using maven.